# To what class of complexity theory a problem for whom I can’t check the solution, ever, belong?

Tags: complexity-theory

Let’s say I have a problem that can only be solved with a trapdoor, but regardless of whether the trapdoor is right or wrong, you can’t check if you have found the solution to the problem. To what class of complexity theory does such a problem belong? And more importantly, can a quantum computer solve such a problem?

Comment: Can you give an example of such a problem? I don't find it conceivable.

Comment: Well that would be the hard part, but I wanna know if that’ll be uncrackable by a quantum computer. That way I’ll know I’m using my time right by finding such a problem

Comment: I think you're wasting your time.

Comment: Can you give a clear mathematical definition of the properties you want? I'm struggling to understand how it's not a contradictory definition.

Comment: Consider an encryption mechanism, caesar cipher for example, where the trapdoor can be the shift. Now If u wanna decode a given encrypted message, no matter if u have the correct trapdoor or not, u will get output but u can never tell if the output is correct or not.

Comment: And ignore the obvious problems that  Caesar cipher has, like how it can be brute-forced or reverse engineered through character distribution or how the output can be confirmed via let's say a deep learning algorithm to be correct or not

Comment: How would the receiver ever decode the message, even if she has the trapdoor?

Comment: @Mark S With a shift (the trapdoor) of 1 and message ‘abc’, the encrypted form would be ‘bcd’. Now on the decoder side with the trapdoor, one can easily decrypt it as ‘abc’. But u see how if u have the wrong or correct trapdoor, u get an answer but do not have any information about whether the decrypted message is wrong or correct.

Comment: I don’t understand how you could easily decrypt it as ‘abc’ - how would you know that’s correct? At any rate I recommend you check out post-quantum cryptography for various ideas about cryptographic protocols that are even hard for quantum computers to decipher. Othrriwse good luck!

Comment: That’s exactly the point, you can’t tell if what you have is correct, so the only way to be absolutely sure that you’re indeed correct, is to have the trapdoor.

Comment: @ShahidKhan That's not what he meant. How do the receiver knows they have the correct trapdoor/they correctly deciphered the message? What you describe is exactly a One-Time Pad: even if you test the correct trapdoor (key), you can't know whether that was indeed the message that was intended, because all messages have the same probability in that case. And even in this case, there has to be a criteria the receiver can use to determine whether they have the correct key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, now I understand what you mean. You want something like the [one-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad), where for any message of the correct length there is an encryption key that gives you that message. It is not possible to check which of the messages is the correct decryption, you need to have the correct encryption key.

It is not possible to solve this problem at all, with a quantum computer or anything. This is proven rigorously in information theory: the encrypted text has zero mutual information with the source text.

As for the complexity class, it doesn't have one. Complexity theory deals with problems where all the necessary information is available.

Comment: So can we use such a system as a security measure against quantum computers?

Comment: Yes, the one-time pad is secure against quantum computers.

Comment: But do bear in mind the "problems" mentioned in Mateus's link, especially the unavoidable difficulty of securely _distributing_ the one-time pad to everyone who _should_ have it and no one who should _not_! Even for personal use, a one-time pad is only as secure as the lockbox you keep it in.

Comment: Yeah what if we could somehow convert this otp to a public key protocol? Wouldn’t that fix the distribution problem? That is, create an unsolvable protocol like this, except it’s a public key protocol like RSA

Comment: @ShahidKhan This question has [an answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25627/why-cant-public-key-encryption-be-perfectly-secure) on Crypto SE. Basically, in a public-key protocol, any adversary can encrypt arbitrary messages using the public key and check whether it matches the ciphertext. This is true for any public-key system. Note also that there is no collision: two messages can't have the same ciphertext otherwise it wouldn't be possible to decrypt it. Thus, there is a criteria an adversary can use to decrypt any ciphertext, so there's no perfect secrecy here.